# How to repeat Column Value if the nextline cell is empty

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

Input File

```
CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT  
11      0   DAS     YES 
CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT
12      0   ECT     YES
CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT
13      0   VAS     YES
        1   DAS     NO
CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT
14      0   SAT     YES
CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT
15      0   CDT     YES
        1   VEG     YES
        2   GAT     NO
```

Expect output:

```
 CARD   SG   CLASS   ATT
 11     0   DAS      YES    
 12     0   ECT      YES
 13     0   VAS      YES
 13     1   DAS      NO
 14     0   SAT      YES
 15     0   CDT      YES
 15     1   VEG      YES
 15     2   GAT      NO
```

What I have done:

```
awk ' /YES|NO/{VAL=$1};/ATT/{Print "CARD" "SG" "CLASS" "ATT" };/YES|NO/{ print VAL, $2, $3, $4} ' SCGR.txt  | column -t   

11  0    DAS  YES
12  0    ECT  YES
13  0    VAS  YES
1   DAS  NO
14  0    SAT  YES
15  0    CDT  YES
1   VEG  YES
2   GAT  NO
```

Please me help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debuging your one ligner -- Several minor problems:

- `Print` -- `print`
- `/ATT/{Print "CARD" "SG" "CLASS" "ATT" }` -- `/ATT/{print}` or `/ATT/;`
- `/YES|NO/{VAL=$1}` is also trigered in the 3 fields records, cleaning the previously saved value. (change the order or `$4 ~ /YES|NO/`)

A variant:

```
awk 'NF==4{v=$1;print} NF==3{print v,$0}'
```

removing extra headers and indenting:

```
awk '/^CARD/ && NR>1 { next } 
     NF==4           { v=$1;print } 
     NF==3           { print v,$0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (assuming all header rows are exactly equal):

```
awk '  NR==1{header=$0; count=NF; print; next}
       ($0~header) {next}
       (NF==count) {col1=$1}
       (NF<count)  {printf("%s",col1)}
       1 ' infile | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

If we don't care about column alignment and just want normalized blank-separated data, the basic pattern is:

```
awk -F' +' '{ $1 = ($1 ~ /^$/ ? prev : $1); prev = $1; print }'
```

See, if we set up a custom field separator which is not equal to the default space, we achieve true separation of fields. If the record begins with a match for the separator, then an empty field is delimited.

By default, Awk does not separate; it tokenizes: it extracts from each record tokens which are sequences of one or more non-blank/non-newline characters. This means that leading and trailing blanks/newlines are ignored. Thus if you have a missing column 1, the value in column 2 becomes column 1.

With our `/ +/` separator regex, we get true separation behavior. A record with leading and trailing spaces like `1 2 3 4` is treated as `<SEP>1<SEP>2<SEP>3<SEP>4<SEP>`. Thus there are six fields: `""`, `"1"`, ..., `"4"`, `""`.  There is a field before the first `<SEP>` and after the last.

By the way, if the first record might have a missing field, we obviously need a default for `prev`.  We also don't want the logic to apply to headings. Also let's replace the ternary operator with an `if`: Thus:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = " +"; prev = 0 }
     NR == 1
     NR > 1 { if ($1 == "") $1 = prev
              print
              prev = $1 }'
FOO BAR BAZ
FOO BAR BAZ
  2 3 4
0 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
  2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for education **sed**'s decision

```
sed '
    1b                             #output 1st line (header)
    $!N                            #add next line to operate 2 lines altogether
    s/\(.*\)\n\(CARD.*\)/\2\n\1/   #move line with CARD to first place 
    /^CARD/D                       #delete line with CARD and go to start
    s/^\(\([0-9]*\s*\).*\n\)\s\s*/\1\2/ 
                                   #repeat 1st field of 1st line if empty in 2nd
    /\n/{P;D}                      #print&remove 1st line, go to start 
    '
```

Comment: Thanks Costas for your input, can you explain step by step how it works.

Comment: Hey I Never did that, I don't even have enough privilege to vote yet.